# Objective C (pass by reference)

Tags: objective-c, nserror

I'm learning about passing `NSError` pointers and the book talks about the pointer "*becoming*" an instance of an `NSError`.

I have no background in computer science but this seems wrong.

Does a pointer become an object, or does it point to a future allocation of memory that occurs at instantiation?
Does the object get initialized and the pointer remains where it is in memory?

And finally, what are the specific things that happen when an object instantiates specifically in the context of `NSError` and the pointer I passed to the method?

Answer (score 5):

I made a diagram I hope explains what's happening. The boxes on the left show what the program variables contain as the code runs. The right side shows pseudocode for the app. You can see how an NSError reference is returned to the caller of `-doSomething:`...

[image]

Comment: not sure how to show this image larger, but if you zoom in in your browser you can make it out

Answer (score 4):

> the book talks about the pointer "becoming" an instance of an `NSError`.

This is wrong. The pointer remains a pointer. However, since all objects in Objective-C are referenced through pointers, `NSError` pointers are passed by double pointers, i.e. `NSError**`:

```
-(void)checkError:(NSError**)errPtr {
    if (errorCondition) {
        *errPtr = [NSError errorWithDomain:... code:... userInfo:...];
    }
}
```

After you make this call when `errorCondition` is true,

```
NSError *error = nil;
[self checkError:&error];
```

`error` will be referencing a newly created `NSError` object, letting you pass a new instance back to the caller. This becomes handy when more than one object could be returned from a method invocation.

Comment: Often passing the error pointer is optional, so it should be `if (errorCondition && errPtr) { ... }`.

Comment: @Droppy This is an illustration of the concept with many missing pieces. I'm sure OP will figure out how to treat a double-pointer to make it optional.